# IntelliJ Debug as vs java -jar Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, debugging, spring-boot, intellij-idea

When I run a Spring Boot 1.3.5 application from console via java -jar target xxxx.jar, it runs perfectly. Instead, when I run it from my IntelliJ going to the Application class, right-click on class name and Debug as 'Application.main()', it starts and stops really fast. I can only get to see the following message.

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:35472', transport: 'socket'
SLF4J: The requested version 1.7.16 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.5.RELEASE)

nov 30, 2017 3:54:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Starting service Tomcat
nov 30, 2017 3:54:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
nov 30, 2017 3:54:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
nov 30, 2017 3:54:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Stopping service Tomcat
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:35472', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why isn't it working as always (first time I see this problem)?. I'd like to be able to wun my application in debug mode from my IntelliJ.

Comment: If you "run as" instead of "debug as", does it do the same error?

Comment: Did u try clean + package and then debug?

Comment: @Nathan, yes,exactly the same

Comment: @ajc nope, and it actually behaves differently. I know the difference between install and package, but I don't see why it implies a difference for this. Could you explain why, please? Thanks (still having different erros related to Files Not Found

Comment: @ldepablo You were probably running an old configuration, or with an old package... The FileNotFound are another problem, but at least it's easily resolved ^^ I'll let ajc precise what could be wrong with your config

Comment: Please try to change the scope for tomcat-* dependencies to "compile". Currently "provided" scope is not added in the classpath by IDE when you run the application, see  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141591#comment=27-1016781 .

Comment: @Andrey no tomcat dependencies, but thanks

Comment: It works you if you just run with no debug in intellj?